How to send a dictionary from template html to view in Django?
url.py path is
path("listingpage/<int:listing_id>/",views.listingpage,name="listingpage"),
path("listingpage/",views.listingpage,name="listingpage"),

template file is
<h2><a href="{% url 'listingpage'  %}?{{listing|urlencode}}">{{listing.title}}</a></h2> 

listing is the dictionary  which I want to send, urlencode method is not working
view file is not implemented
def listingpage(request,listing_id=None):
    print(request.GET)  
    print("printing dictionary")


Sending something like a dictionary would be better using ajax rather than as a query param.

@15800954  in that case other using ajax is there anyway way to pass a list of dictionary from one view to another? request.session['listname']=list  is unfortunately not working for me causing key error. Thenks

Well it can be done either as query params, but since a dict can be too long and you dont really want to use a dict as a query param when accessing a page, what you can do is to do it as a form submission, Im not sure how you would structure it on the page, but you can submit it as a form data.

Research more and post a [mre] including the detailed information on the listing. Anyway, you need to serialize Python dictionary.

urlencode won't work on a dictionary it needs a string. Anyway as suggested by others the querystring is not a suitable means to send a dictionary to the server a POST request with the dictionary serialized into JSON would be much better. In your particular case it just looks like you're trying to send the object you want your page to display in the request? Why doesn't your view handle loading that object from the database or the suitable data source?
